# Modify mutliple .xml files in a directory using python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to modify multiple .xml files that are in a folder and overwrite the files with their original files names.

I can successfully modify one file, but when I try to add code to go through multiple files, nothing changes. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Could anyone assist? Thank you.

Also, a beginner in Python.

Here is the XML file that I am changing:

```
<annotation>
    <folder>Images</folder>
    <filename>1.jpg</filename>
    <path>/Users/AAA/Desktop/data/imgs</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>1021</width>
        <height>1500</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>backpack</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>1</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>6</xmin>
            <ymin>1</ymin>
            <xmax>1021</xmax>
            <ymax>1466</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

This is what it should look like:

```
<annotation>
    <folder>backpack</folder>
    <filename>1.jpg</filename>
    <source>
        <database>backpack</database>
        <annotation>custom</annotation>
        <image>custom</image>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>1021</width>
        <height>1500</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>backpack</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>1</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>6</xmin>
            <ymin>1</ymin>
            <xmax>1021</xmax>
            <ymax>1466</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

Here is my python code attempt to try modify multiple files from a folder:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xml.dom.minidom
import os

dir = 'Desktop/python_testing/xml/'

if os.path.isfile(dir):

    mytree = ET.parse(dir, '*.xml')
    myroot = mytree.getroot()

    # changes description of the elements
    for description in myroot.iter('folder'):
        new_desc = 'backpack'
        description.text = str(new_desc)

    for database in myroot.iter('database'):
        new_desc = 'backpack'
        database.tail = '\n\t\t'
        database.text = str(new_desc)

    # adds additional subchild items annotation and image
    source = myroot.find('source')
    annotate = ET.SubElement(source, 'annotation') 
    annotate.tail = '\n\t\t'
    annotate.text = 'custom'

    source = myroot.find('source')
    img = ET.SubElement(source, 'image')
    img.tail = '\n\t'
    img.text = 'custom'
    
    #remove <path> element
    path = myroot.getchildren()[2]
    myroot.remove(path)
    
    mytree.write(dir, '*.xml')
```

Comment: `Desktop/python_testing/xml/` is a directory, so `os.path.isfile()` will return False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `ElementTree` to open multiple files in a single invocation. Simply loop over them:

```
# your other imports...
import glob

dir = 'Desktop/python_testing/xml/'

for xml_file in glob.glob(dir + '/*.xml'):
    mytree = ET.parse(xml_file)

    # make your changes here...

    mytree.write(xml_file)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Actually here there is an unnecessary extra `/`, but it does no harm and I included the `/` before the `*.xml` in case `dir` doesn't have a trailing slash. (The alternative is to use `os.path.join`.)